# Custom css media queries not working with bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 with jquery UI to have search and select field for the user. The css code works fine on larger screen but absolutely not working with the smaller screen. I'm using following media query code but it is not taking effect. In fact I observed my custom css code does not work with any of the @media queries. I'm using bootstrap3 across the website. Any ideas please?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .ui-autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1000;
        float: left;
        display: none;
        min-width: 160px;   
        padding: 4px 0;
        margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-color: #ccc;
        border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        -moz-background-clip: padding;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        *border-right-width: 2px;
        *border-bottom-width: 2px;
    }

.ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 15px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 18px;
        color: #555555;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.ui-state-hover, .ui-state-active {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #0088cc;
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        background-image: none;
    } 

    }
```

Comment: And the HTML please?

Comment: After all the struggle I found a workaround and created a separate media.css file and linked it at the end of all other css files. I'm making media queries through that file and its working. Somehow bootstrap css overwrites whatever css I wrote in my custom css file.

Comment: <head>  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> </head>

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body{
            background:red;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            body{
                background:green;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```